# How do I create a bug in TFS using REST API in PowerShell?

Tags: rest, api, powershell, tfs, workitem

I am trying to create a bug in TFS using REST API in PowerShell with the code below, but I'm unable to figure out how to fill the `$Bug` variable with names of those param's and data.

```
Param(
   [string]$vstsAccount = "MyAccountName",
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "Mytoken"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
#$uri = "https://$($vstsAccount).visualstudio.com/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/workitems/$Bug?api-version=2.2"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

I could find a sample for C# [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/samples#create-bug), but not for PowerShell. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: For one, you aren't sending the server any data with a `GET` request.

Comment: It seems `$Bug` is not a variable but part of the url. So you need to escape it: "`$bug" (mind the backtick!)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, Thanks for response, yes I corrected my mistake and before that I tried POST as well later I used Patch as suggested by Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a **JSON body** to use the REST API to create a work item in PowserShell, and the `Content-Type` should be `application/json-patch+json`, also use `PATCH` method. See [Create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item) for details.

You can reference below sample PowerShell script to create a bug:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "token"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "0925Bug"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
    "value": "LCScrum"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
    "value": "LCScrum\\Sprint 1"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Tags",
    "value": "Tag0921;Tag0926;Tag0927;Tag0928"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity",
    "value": "Development"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort",
    "value": "8"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea",
    "value": "Business"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity",
    "value": "3 - Medium"
  },
  {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value":
        {
            "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Forward",
            "url": "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/324",
            "attributes":
            {
               "usage": "workItemLink",
               "editable": false,
               "enabled": true,
               "acyclic": true,
               "directional": true,
               "singleTarget": true,
               "topology": "dependency"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value":
        {
            "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
            "url": "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/58",
            "attributes":
            {
              "usage": "workItemLink",
              "editable": false,
              "enabled": true,
              "acyclic": true,
              "directional": true,
              "singleTarget": false,
              "topology": "tree"
            }
        }
    }
]
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/workitems/"+"$"+"bug?api-version=2.2"
Write-Host $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for that answer and it was useful, however i had few more following up issues..Like Bug that are getting created are not visible under the project(backlog)but the same can be seen only when tap on the project name left top corner of the screen. when i checked it again its happening because its not getting created under any spritnt/iteration.

Comment: 2) how do i figure out the all other fields that can be added to Json object to create issues, like the Tags, Iteration, effort etc(Name of the field, path etc)

Comment: @SCode Just following the instruction for each Parameter mentioned in this link: [Create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item). Anyway, I have updated the answer, you can reference the sample to change the value accordingly.

Comment: that perfectly worked for me, Thanks a ton. I was exploring adding multiple tags while creating bug, I tried to repeat the tags code block one after the another but it just took the later one as tag and only one tag got created. Any information on adding multiple tags?  currently i am planning to do it while creating it self and not updating the bug again...Thanks in advance..

Comment: "value": "Tag0921;Tag0926;Tag0927;Tag0928" this one works, is there are a  way I can add these data from an array? meaning dynamic data? for instance I tried Data[$i][0] ;Data[$i][1] and "Data[$i][0] ;Data[$i][1]" in both of them object is getting added and not data...Also tried with $ as well